# Geometry of super-rigidid elliptic curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Consider a Calabi-Yau threefold $X$ with an elliptic curve $E$ living inside it. Furthermore, assume $E$ is super-rigid, i.e., for any *stable* map from a nonsingular curve $\mu:C\to E$ we have $H^0(C,\mu^*(N_{E|X}))=0$. In particular it's rigid, i.e., $H^0(E,N_{E|X})=0$. I'm trying to understand the geometric implications of super-rigidity.

Then (see 1.1 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9811140.pdf)) rigidity implies that there is a short exact sequence:
$$
0\to L\to N\to L^\vee\to 0,
$$
where $L$ is a non-trivial degree 0 line bundle (I think I can show this).

On the other hand, in the paper linked above it's claimed that super-rigidity is equivalent to $L$ being a nontorsion element of $Pic^0 E$, which I don't know how to prove. Any help with it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $L$ is non torsion, then its pullback to any curve mapping dominantly to $E$ is also non torsion (the pullback map has finite kernel). On the other hand if $L$ is torsion then it becomes trivial on some curve (which can be taken to be elliptic) mapping dominantly to $E$.

Comment: Dear @ulrich, thanks for your reply! Your comment solves my question and made me realize its elementary nature. If you feel like posting it as an answer I'll gladly accept it.